# Why is there a difference between the Stack Exchange sites Mathematics and Physics?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have a question. Why does the *Physics* Stack Exchange site not encourage homework-like questions while the *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site does, or in the very least, does not close those questions. Why is there a disparity??

Comment: *Why is there a disparity?* It isn’t surprising that different communities make different decisions.

Comment: For some historical links about our homework policy, see this answer: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10079/44126

Comment: If you are looking for homework help, you could try here: https://www.physicsforums.com/

Comment: They are not only closing homework, they are closing things they just don't like based on random whims and personal biases. Are they allowing reasonable questions over at math SE? Maybe we could go over there, probably some are interested in the more applied type of questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have a question. Why Physics StackExchange does not encourage homework like questions while Math StackExchange does, or in the very least, does not close those questions.

We've had attempts (on Meta) to change the no-homework policy and it has been consistently voted to keep as is.

It's something the community wants.

Note we do not ban homework completely.  We do require homework type questions to be focused on explaining concepts (and not to have been answered before).  Many people literally post homework questions with little more than a "how do I do this".

I'm not sure I'd agree that there's a huge difference on Math SE, however even if there is, that would not change the fact that Physics SE members have voted to maintain the homework policy here consistently.  There's no requirement for different SE's to have the same community policies, not least because they have different communities.